# Outlook add-in with Visual Studio 2013 not works

Tags: visual-studio-2013, add-in, outlook-addin

I created a small add-in outlook project with visual studio 2013. When I run the add-in for the 1st time, it works. But if I start outlook and that I remove this add-in, when I want to launch it again from visual studio to debug for example, the add-in is no more taken into account by outlook. What does do to solve this problem?

Comment: If the answer was useful to you or solved your problem, please mark it as correct. Otherwise, give us more detail if the solution did not work and we can attempt to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a VSTO based add-in you just need to build it to get it registered anew.

Typically the windows registry keys allow to detect what add-ins are registered and then load them. Read more about the required windows registry keys in the [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106(v=vs.110).aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't no why, but only do a build or re-build the add-in is not enough. But with you information about registry, if I delete the entry for the add-in, then build it then it works anew.

Answer (score 0):

You must rebuild the project within Visual Studio. Once you do a Rebuild it will load into Outlook the next time that you run the debugger.